# hy, I am learning solidity, and am deploying a contract with local javascript, and encounter a problem in the powershell:

Tags: solidity, javascript, nodejs

here the error:

```
PS C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\31_hrs_blockchain\ethers-simple-storage> node deploy.js
Deploying, please wait...
TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="deployed", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.3.0)
    at makeError (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\31_hrs_blockchain\ethers-simple-storage\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\errors.js:114:21)
    at assert (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\31_hrs_blockchain\ethers-simple-storage\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\errors.js:138:15)
    at assertArgument (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\31_hrs_blockchain\ethers-simple-storage\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\errors.js:150:5)
    at Interface.getFunctionName (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\31_hrs_blockchain\ethers-simple-storage\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\abi\interface.js:337:39)
    at buildWrappedMethod (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\31_hrs_blockchain\ethers-simple-storage\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\contract\contract.js:234:34)
    at BaseContract.getFunction (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\31_hrs_blockchain\ethers-simple-storage\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\contract\contract.js:625:22)
    at Object.get (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\31_hrs_blockchain\ethers-simple-storage\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\contract\contract.js:560:39)
    at main (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\31_hrs_blockchain\ethers-simple-storage\deploy.js:20:44)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'key',
  value: 'deployed'
}
```

and here my code:

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs");
const { JsonRpcProvider } = require("ethers/providers");

const main = async () => {
  // http://127.0.0.1:7545
  const provider = new JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545");
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0xa4b82584cfbd22454a976eb3a2a68a430010a56da6f25e08d8ee72d5203f7d90",
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf8"
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy({});
  const deploymentreceipt = await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
  console.log(deploymentreceipt);
};

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error arises in the manner you are using `deploy()`.

You can use ethers to instantiate a contract from the factory like this

```
import { ContractFactory } from 'ethers';

const factory = new ContractFactory(contractAbi, contractByteCode);

const contract = await factory.deploy(deployArgs);

console.log(contract.address);
console.log(contract.deployTransaction);
```

..more info is available [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/)